# Group by a column and display all the column values linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hello All this is my datatable input and output, I want to do it using linq Query

Input Data Table

`C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 
 a  1  2  3
 b  4  5
 c  6  7  7  9 
 b  11 12 13
 a  10 
 b  111`

Output Data table

`C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
 a  1  2  3  10
 b  4  5  11 12 13 111
 c  6  7  7  9`

I need to do it using linq

so first what i did is i got the max number of elements per id(C1) to add that many number of columns as you can see first i had 5 columns than due to id(c1) **b** i had to add two more column i did that using a combination of add range and enumerable range.

Next the main processing i was trying to directly add values using LinQ(i know its a query language and should be used as one) i was only trying

what i was thinking is to group the column C1 then display all the values in the reamining columns and join it using string.join method and than later add the data one by on

the code i used does'nt work as i am unable to dynamically get all the columns...We can get single columns string.joined value but we cannot all columns values as a string..... Any suggestion the code which i was trying to use

```
(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Group roww By id=roww.Item("ID") 
 Into gg = Group Let x=CStr(gg(0)(1))+"|"+String.Join("|",gg.Select(Function(r) CStr(r(DT.Columns.Cast(Of datacolumn).Select(Function(col) (col.columnname)))))     )
Select DT.Clone.Rows.Add(x.Split("|"c))).copytodatatable
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three answers in this post all are great but I found a another solution which can be done in less and simpler steps.....

SO my flow goes like this first I Read my data table(**DT1**) -> I also create another Data table(**DT2**) with just a single column **ID** -> I get the max number of value's an ID has using this code

`CInt(String.Join("|",(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
String.Join("|",(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Group roww By id=roww.Item("C1") Into gg = Group 
Let x=String.Join(",",From p In gg.AsEnumerable() Select String.Join(",",p.ItemArray.Where(Function(r) r.ToString<>"" ) ))
Select x).ToList).Trim,"(?<=,)[a-zA-Z](?=,),","").Split("|"c).Select(Function(co) System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(co,"\d+").Count ).max)))`

-->then i add that number of columns in my **DT2** using **Columns.Add range** method
-->Then the final step is i assign the **DT2** with this code and the data is manipulated and inserted in to the **DT2** the code is this --->

`(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Group roww By id=roww.Item("C1") Into gg = Group 
Let x=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String.Join("|",(String.Join(",",From p In gg.AsEnumerable() Select String.Join(",",p.ItemArray.Where(Function(r) r.ToString<>"" )))).Split(","c).
OrderByDescending(Function(o) CStr(o))),"^.+(?=[a-zA-Z])","")
Select DT_Edited.Rows.Add(x.split("|"c))).copytodatatable`

and by this way we successfully we get the desired output...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(x=>x.Field<string>("C1"))
                    .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("C1"))
                    .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key,y=>y.ToList().SelectMany(x=>x.ItemArray)
                    .Where(x=>x!=DBNull.Value).OfType<int>())
                    .ToCustomDataTable<int>();
```

Where `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<T>>.ToCustomDataTable<T>` is defined as

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DataTable ToCustomDataTable<T>(this Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("C1",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(2,source.Values.Select(x=>x.Count()).Max()).Select((x,index)=> new DataColumn($"C{index+2}",typeof(T))).ToArray());
        foreach(var key in source.Keys)
        {
            var values = new List<object>();
            values.Add(key);
            values.AddRange(source[key].Cast<object>());
            dt.Rows.Add(values.ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a1ykAW)

Comment: hello @Anu Viswan can you explain to me in detail about this *Where Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<T>>.ToCustomDataTable<T> is defined as* as i have never defined anything when using linq i used to use simple queries without defining any.........Another thing is why cannot i use *.Copytodatatable* method in this query i am successfully getting the code before the .ToCustomDataTable<int>(); but after that i cannot thanks for your time

Comment: @Vickydas ToCustomDataTable<T> is an extension method defined as shown in the code above. You would need to add it to your solution as well.Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types, without modifying the original types. In the code above, you are adding an extension method to Type Dictionary<string,IEnumerble<T>>

Comment: @Vickydas Please let me know if you need further clarification or help.

Comment: Hello @AnuViswan although your answer is great and correct but i cannot use this in my automation tool as there is no way to define a custom method (Currently).What if i create a datatable with all the necessary columns and then use this code before the *.ToCustomDatatable<t>* then can i use the *.Copytodatatable* method with the Datatable i have created  Or any other way to convert it into datatable or add rows into datatable ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Vickydas what is the automation tool you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

First, i have created this list to test my code,

```
    var list = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string>(){"a","1","2","3" }, new List<string>(){"b","4","5" },
                  new List<string>(){"c","6","7","7","9" }, new List<string>(){"b","11","12","13" }, new List<string>(){"a","10" }, new List<string>(){"b","111" } };
```

Then implement the following code,

```
        var verticalList = list.GroupBy(x => x.First(), y=> y.Skip(1).ToList(), 
            (key,rest) => rest.Count() > 1 ? rest.Aggregate((a, b) => MyAdd(key, a, b)) : MyAdd2(key,rest.First())).ToList();

        var vertical = verticalList.Max(y => y.Count);
        var horizontal = verticalList.Count();
        var result = new string[vertical, horizontal];
        for(int i=0; i<vertical; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < horizontal; j++)
                if(verticalList[j].ElementAtOrDefault(i)!=null)
                result[i, j] = verticalList[j][i];


        List<string> MyAdd(string key, List<string> res, List<string> item) {
            if(!res.Contains(key))
            res.Insert(0, key);
            res.AddRange(item);
            return res;
        }
        List<string> MyAdd2(string key, List<string> res) {
            res.Insert(0, key);
            return res;
        }
```

> **result** keeps the data as you want

.

### **If you want to see output, try with the following**,

```
        for (int i = 0; i < horizontal; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < vertical; j++) {
                Console.Write(result[j, i] + " ");
            }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

> prints
>
> a 1 2 3 10
>
> b 4 5 11 12 13 111
>
> c 6 7 7 9

Full code as shown below,

```
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var list = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string>(){"a","1","2","3" }, new List<string>(){"b","4","5" },
              new List<string>(){"c","6","7","7","9" }, new List<string>(){"b","11","12","13" }, new List<string>(){"a","10" }, new List<string>(){"b","111" } };

        var verticalList = list.GroupBy(x => x.First(), y => y.Skip(1).ToList(),
       (key, rest) => rest.Count() > 1 ? rest.Aggregate((a, b) => MyAdd(key, a, b)) : MyAdd2(key, rest.First())).ToList();

        var vertical = verticalList.Max(y => y.Count);
        var horizontal = verticalList.Count();
        var result = new string[vertical, horizontal];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertical; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < horizontal; j++)
                if (verticalList[j].ElementAtOrDefault(i) != null)
                    result[i, j] = verticalList[j][i];

        List<string> MyAdd(string key, List<string> res, List<string> item)
        {
            if (!res.Contains(key))
                res.Insert(0, key);
            res.AddRange(item);
            return res;
        }
        List<string> MyAdd2(string key, List<string> res)
        {
            res.Insert(0, key);
            return res;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < horizontal; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < vertical; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(result[j, i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: hello Furkan can you post the full code i am getting an error while using this code dont know why

Comment: I guess you get error by **MyAdd** and **MyAdd2**. You need to  put them in the scope as i share above

Comment: Hello Furkan Ozturk thank your for your time to upload the full code..........Let me explain you the logic once what we are doing here is we are creating a dictionary with key and adding all the containing elements of that particular key together and then we can add it into our datatable as rows right ?

Comment: I am sorry  but i didn't get whether you are talking about your logic or wanting suggestion?

Comment: hello Furkan i am asking about logic\

Comment: Hi Vicky, in first linq i just grouped them by a,b or c to get the output {a,1,2,3,10},{b,4,5,11,12,13,111},{c,6,7,7,9}. Then i get the horizontal and vertical length to know the size of table i will create(rotated table). At the last, i fill data  to rotated table(you can consider this as a matrix) by for loop to provide the output as you want @Vickydas

Answer (score -1):

Try following.  I used a datatable :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("C3", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("C4", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("C5", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a", 1, 2, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "b", 4, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "c", 6, 7, 8, 9 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "b", 11, 12, 13 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a", 10 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "b", 111 });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("C1"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("C1"))
                .ToList();

            int maxColumns = groups.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.ItemArray.Where(z => z != DBNull.Value).Count() - 1).Sum()).Max();

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 1; i <= maxColumns; i++)
            {
                dt2.Columns.Add("C" + (i + 1).ToString(), typeof(int));
            }

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                List<object> data = new List<object>() { group.Key };
                List<object> numbers = group.SelectMany(x => x.ItemArray.Skip(1).Where(y => y != DBNull.Value).Select(y => y)).ToList();
                data.AddRange(numbers);
                dt2.Rows.Add(data.ToArray());
            }

        }
    }

}
```